# Is posting citations a compulsion even when the post contains self experiences?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, quality, copyright

I have posted an answer for a post [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/my-dog-lies-down-on-its-stomach-with-legs-wide-open/7183#7183), for which I got the below notification.

[image: Notification which I received on posting: "This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed."]

Now, what I don't understand here is why am I being asked to add citations to reliable resources, when there is no reference regarding compulsory citation given in the help section on any SO affiliated sites. There is only a mention regarding that if I am copying some material, only then I need to add the reference site/citation from where I copied it.

Whereas, in the above case, it's my own personal experiences which I have clearly mentioned.

I agree by this [post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/must-answers-provide-citations-if-using-external-sources-and-if-so-how-should) that SE abides by the laws regarding any copyright issues and needs citations only when copying data/content from other sites.

But when I have not done any sort of copying data/text from other sites but my own personal experiences, then isn't this a wrong notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that citations are not required. But as written, [your answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/my-dog-lies-down-on-its-stomach-with-legs-wide-open/7183#7183) has three points; one (the last) is from personal experience and the first two appear to be opinion or common knowledge.

Additionally, your answer adds nothing that is not already posted in existing answers.

There is a post [here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/774) that talks about some of the problems with short answers.

None of the answers on the question [My dog lies down on its stomach with legs wide open](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/) are [particularly good](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

There is much room to write good answers to the questions, and your post could be the start of one. Adding references and expanding on the "why" would improve the answer considerably.  You may also find while researching that there are things you had not expected.

Comment: thanks for the reply i would keep in mind next time for giving citations from a valuable resource and also not simply give a referrence